# ChannelHandler handling content of unknown size

Tags: apache-camel, netty

I am still struggling with Camel (2.16.1) and Netty (4.0.33) to have them both receive tcp content of freely chosen length. Because of the unknown size of the tcp content received I was not yet able to create a working decoder for.

Let me describe my problem with an example. Lets say I have a file with a length of 3129 byte. When I `nc` that file to my route the size is not known until the last byte is read:

`cat file.bin | nc localhost 10001`

My route is defined like this:

```
from( "netty4:tcp://127.0.0.1:10001?sync=false&allowDefaultCodec=false&
      decoder=#factory&receiveBufferSize=1000000")
.to("file:/temp/in");
```

The factory looks like this because I need to make sure that each ChannelHandler is used only once:

```
public class Factory implements ChannelHandlerFactory {
    @Override
    public ChannelHandler newChannelHandler() {
        return new RawPrinterDecoder();
    }
}
```

In my decoder I have this code:

```
public class RawPrinterDecoder extends ReplayingDecoder<Void> {
    @Override
    protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in,
            List<Object> out) throws Exception {
        while (in.isReadable()) {
            byte readByte = in.readByte();
            job.addContent(readByte);
        }

        in.discardReadBytes();
    }

    public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Bytes in job: " + job.getSize() );
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that instead of 3129 byte I receive 9273. The reason for this is that the file is split into 3 segments of 1024 byte and 1 with 57 byte. Those are passed repeatedly to my decoder and although I try to invalidate the segments after they are first processed with `in.discardReadBytes()` they are processed again so instead of ...

- segment1
- segment2
- segment3
- segment4

... my decoder sees them like this

- segment1
- segment1+segment2
- segment1+segment2+segment3
- segment1+segment2+segment3+segment4

I tried so solve my problem by using `checkpoint()` but the segments were still called repeatedly.

How can I make sure that each segment is only processed once and in the correct order ? If this can be done more efficiently instead of reading single bytes recommendations are welcome (`readableBytes()` always return 2 GB so I can not use this to get the number of bytes).

Answer (score 0):

It gets seperated into segments because of the ByteBuffAllocator that your server is using. You can change that this way:

```
@Bean
public ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> channelInitializer() {
    return new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
        @Override
        public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
            ch.config().setRecvByteBufAllocator(new FixedRecvByteBufAllocator(2048));
        }
    };
}
```

You can read all of the available bytes at once using:

```
ByteBuf buffer = in.readBytes(in);
```

or

```
ByteBuf buffer = in.readSlice(in.readableBytes());
```